# How to generate release key in android

Tags: android-maps

i've done simple map application.Here i got api key from debug.keystore .Its working fine on emulator.when i try to get it as apk file & run that on device.,it didnt display map.i think i need to create release key for that.How can i generate release key for that & how can i make my appn signed with that key.Anybody let me know the procedures for that.i used http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html. But im not much clear.

Answer (score 4):

You have to generate a key for the certficate you use to sign your .apk file. Look [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)  to get step by step instructions on this.

Comment: what would be the decrypt passphrase if i left them blank?